# Sequence of constructor calls in complex multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

I have a doubt in understanding statement

> name = SizedRegexString(maxlen=8, pat='[A-Z]+$')

in the code below. I am not able to understand how init calls are happening up in the hierarchy.

```
# Example of defining descriptors to customize attribute access.

from inspect import Parameter, Signature
import re
from collections import OrderedDict


class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        print("inside desc")
        self.name = name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete")


class Typed(Descriptor):
    ty = object

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.ty):
            raise TypeError('Expected %s' % self.ty)
        super().__set__(instance, value)


class String(Typed):
    ty = str


# Length checking
class Sized(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self, *args, maxlen, **kwargs):
        print("inside sized")
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if len(value) > self.maxlen:
            raise ValueError('Too big')
        super().__set__(instance, value)


class SizedString(String, Sized):
    pass


# Pattern matching
class Regex(Descriptor):
    def __init__(self, *args, pat, **kwargs):
        print("inside regex")
        self.pat = re.compile(pat)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not self.pat.match(value):
            raise ValueError('Invalid string')
        super().__set__(instance, value)


class SizedRegexString(SizedString, Regex):
    pass


# Structure definition code
def make_signature(names):
    return Signature(
        Parameter(name, Parameter.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD)
        for name in names)


class StructMeta(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, name, bases):
        return OrderedDict()

    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, clsdict):
        fields = [key for key, val in clsdict.items()
                  if isinstance(val, Descriptor) ]
        for name in fields:
            clsdict[name].name = name

        clsobj = super().__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dict(clsdict))
        sig = make_signature(fields)
        setattr(clsobj, '__signature__', sig)
        return clsobj


class Structure(metaclass=StructMeta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bound = self.__signature__.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, val in bound.arguments.items():
            setattr(self, name, val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    class Stock(Structure):
        name = SizedRegexString(maxlen=8, pat='[A-Z]+$')


    for item in SizedRegexString.__mro__:
        print(item)
```

Output from print statements inside init:

```
inside sized
inside regex
inside desc
inside desc
inside desc
```

Output from mro of SizedRegexString class

```
<class '__main__.SizedRegexString'>
<class '__main__.SizedString'>
<class '__main__.String'>
<class '__main__.Typed'>
<class '__main__.Sized'>
<class '__main__.Regex'>
<class '__main__.Descriptor'>
<class 'object'>
```

Does **init** and **set** both call chains follow the mro? Or there is something else happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not clear on what exactly your question is, so it would be helpful if you could explain precisely what you were expecting to happen, and how that differed from what actually happened. In light of that fact, I’ll try to explain how the MRO is evaluated here.

First, since the class hierarchy in the example code is rather convoluted, it may help to visualize the inheritance structure:

[image]

Turning to your question,

> Does init and set both call chains follow the mro?

If I’m understanding correctly, the short answer is yes. The MRO is determined based on class inheritance and is an attribute of *classes*, not methods. Your loop through `SizedRegexString.__mro__` illustrates this fact, so I’m guessing your question arose from a perceived disparity between the call chains of `__init__` and `__set__`.

## __init__ Call Chain

The call chain for `SizedRegexString.__init__` is as follows:

- `SizedRegexString.__init__`, which is not explicitly defined, so it defers to its superclass’s definition
- `SizedString.__init__`, which is not explicitly defined
- `String.__init__`, which is not explicitly defined
- `Typed.__init__`, which is not explicitly defined
- `Sized.__init__`, which sets `maxlen`, then calls `super().__init__()`
- `Regex.__init__`, which sets `pat`, then calls `super().__init__()`
- `Descriptor.__init__`, which sets `name`

So upon calling `SizedRegexString.__init__`, according to the MRO, there are seven defined classes that need to be checked for an `__init__` method (assuming each calls `super().__init__()`, as well). However, as you noted, the output from print statements inside the `__init__` methods shows that the following classes are visited: `Sized`, `Regex`, and `Descriptor`. Note that these are the same classes - in the same order - as those mentioned in the bullets above as being explicitly defined.

So, to us, it might *seem* like the MRO for `SizedRegexString` is [`Sized`, `Regex`, `Descriptor`] because those are the only three classes we see actually doing things. However, this is not the case. The bulleted MRO above is still adhered to, but none of the classes before `Sized` explicitly define an `__init__` method, so they each silently defer to their superclasses.

## __set__ Call Chain

That explains how `__init__` follows the MRO, but why does `__set__` seem to behave differently? To answer this, we can follow the same bulleted MRO used above:

- `SizedRegexString.__set__`, which is not explicitly defined, so it defers to its superclass’s definition
- `SizedString.__set__`, which is not explicitly defined
- `String.__set__`, which is not explicitly defined
- `Typed.__set__`, which checks that `value` is an instance of `self.ty`, then calls `super().__set__()`
- `Sized.__set__`, which checks the length of `value`, then calls `super().__set__()`
- `Regex.__set__`, which ensures a match between `self.pat` and `value`, then calls `super().__set__()`
- `Descriptor.__set__`, which adds the key/value pair of `self.name` and `value` to `instance.__dict__`

The takeaway here is that `__set__` adheres to the same MRO as `__init__` because they belong to the same class, even though we see activity from four different classes this time, whereas, we only saw three with `__init__`. So, once again, it may *seem* as if the MRO of `SizedRegexString` is now [`Typed`, `Sized`, `Regex`, `Descriptor`]. This can be confusing because this new call chain differs from both `SizedRegexString.__mro__` and from the apparent call chain we saw for `SizedRegexString.__init__`.

## TL;DR

But after following the call chains for both `__init__` and `__set__`, we can see that they both follow the MRO. The disparity comes from the fact that more descendants of `Descriptor` explicitly define the `__set__` method than the `__init__` method.

## Additional Points

Here are a couple other points that may be causing some confusion:

1. None of the `__set__` methods defined are actually called in your example code’s current state. We can figure out why with the following two lines from your example code:

   ```py
   class Stock(Structure):
       name = SizedRegexString(maxlen=8, pat=“[A-Z]+$”)
   ```

   The end product of these two lines (`Stock`) is produced by the `StructMeta` metaclass’s `__new__` method. While `Stock` does have the `name` class attribute that is a `SizedRegexString` instance, no attributes of this instance are being set. Therefore, none of the `__set__` methods are called. Where we do expect `__set__` to be called is in `Stock.__init__`, because of the following lines in `Structure.__init__`:

   ```py
   for n, v in bound.arguments.items():
       setattr(self, n, v)
   ```

   By adding `s = Stock(name=“FOO”)` to the end of your example code, we can see the `__set__` methods executing successfully. Additionally, we can verify that the proper errors are raised by `Regex.__set__` and `Sized.__set__` with `s = Stock(name=“foo”)` and `s = Stock(name=“FOOFOOFOO”)`, respectively
2. After Python 3.6, `dict`s are ordered by default, so the `__prepare__` method in `StructMeta` may be superfluous depending on which Python version you’re using

Hopefully I addressed your question. If I missed the point completely, I’d be happy to try again if you could clarify exactly what you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks for explaining so nicely. This answers my question.